# React useState not rendering the current onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have a quandary on the code I'm trying to execute. I'm using controlled inputs and I'm passing the response from an API to a child component, but it is rendering the last value.

Here is my code.

Ppassing the id of the data row I'm currently trying to display:

```
<AdminInvociceDetail row={invoiceRowClicked} />
```

Component receiving the id

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
 useFetchInvoiceQuery,
 useUpdateInvoiceMutation,
} from "../../features/Invoices/InvoiceSlice";
import { useNavigate, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Admin.css";

const AdminInvociceDetail = ({ row }) => {
  const { data } = useFetchInvoiceQuery(row);
  const [UpdateInvoice] = useUpdateInvoiceMutation();

  //* state for the form
  const [Id, setId] = useState("");
  const [billtoname, setBillToName] = useState("");
  const [clientname, setClientName] = useState("");
  const [offc, setOffc] = useState("");
  const [matterNo, setMatterNo] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setId(data?.ID);
    setBillToName(data?.BillToName);
    setOffc(data?.OFFC);
    setClientName(data?.ClientName);
    setMatterNo(data?.MatterNo);
  }, [row]);

  function ButtonLink({ to, children, className }) {
    return (
      <Link to={to}>
        <button className={className}>{children}</button>
      </Link>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div class="box">
        <form class="ui form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <h4 class="ui dividing header labels">Invoice Detail:</h4>
          <div class="two fields">
            <div class="field">
              <label className="labels">Bill To Name</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="BillToName"
                placeholder="Bill To Name"
                required
                onChange={(e) => setBillToName(e.target.value)}
                value={billtoname || ""}
              />
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <label className="labels">Client Location</label>
              <select
                class="ui fluid dropdown"
                required
                onChange={(e) => setClientName(e.target.value)}
                value={clientname || ""}
              >
                <option value="">Location</option>
                <option value="Becker - Tampa">Becker - Tampa</option>
                <option value="Becker - Orlando">Becker - Orlando</option>
                <option value="Becker - West Palm Beach">
                  Becker - West Palm Beach
                </option>
                <option value="Becker - Fort Myers">Becker - Fort Myers</option>
                <option value="Becker - Coral Gables">
                  Becker - Coral Gables
                </option>
                <option value="Becker - Fort Lauderdale">
                  Becker - Fort Lauderdale
                </option>
                <option value="Becker - Morristown">Becker - Morristown</option>
                <option value="Becker - Bradenton">Becker - Bradenton</option>
                <option value="Becker - Stuart">Becker - Stuart</option>
                <option value="Becker - Naples">Becker - Naples</option>
                <option value="Becker - Sarasota">Becker - Sarasota</option>
                <option value="Becker - Fort Walton Beach">
                  Becker - Fort Walton Beach
                </option>
                <option value="Becker - New York">Becker - New York</option>
                <option value="Becker - Mount Laurel">
                  Becker - Mount Laurel
                </option>
                <option value="Becker - Red Bank">Becker - Red Bank</option>
                <option value="Becker - Tallahassee">
                  Becker - Tallahassee
                </option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="two fields">
            <div class="field">
              <label className="labels">Office</label>
              <select
                class="ui fluid dropdown"
                required
                onChange={(e) => setOffc(e.target.value)}
                name="offc"
                value={offc || ""}
              >
                <option value="">Office</option>
                <option value="TAL">TAL</option>
                <option value="ORL">ORL</option>
                <option value="WPB">WPB</option>
                <option value="FTM">FTM</option>
                <option value="MIA">MIA</option>
                <option value="FTL">FTL</option>
                <option value="MOR">MOR</option>
                <option value="STR">STR</option>
                <option value="NAP">NAP</option>
                <option value="BDT">BDT</option>
                <option value="SAR">SAR</option>
                <option value="FTW">FTW</option>
                <option value="TAM">TAM</option>
                <option value="MTL">MTL</option>
                <option value="MOR">MOR</option>
                <option value="RB">RB</option>
                <option value="NY">NY</option>
                <option value="DC">DC</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <label className="labels">Matter No</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="MatterNo"
                placeholder="Matter No"
                onChange={(e) => setMatterNo(e.target.value)}
                value={matterNo || ""}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <ButtonLink to="/" className="back-button">
            Back to Invoice
          </ButtonLink>
          <button class="submit-button">Submit Invoice</button>
          <div class="fields"></div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

When I click on the rows, the state is lagging behind. Not sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly that the issue is that the local states are not updated correctly to matched the queried data by `row` value, then it seems the issue is that the `useEffect` hook to update the local state has incorrect dependencies.

Instead of using `row` it should use `data`, so that when the queried `data` result updates, the effect can run and update the local state. You could also pass initial state values directly to the `useState` hooks in the case there is already cached query data.

Example:

```js
const AdminInvociceDetail = ({ row }) => {
  const { data } = useFetchInvoiceQuery(row);
  const [UpdateInvoice] = useUpdateInvoiceMutation();

  // state for the form
  const [Id, setId] = useState(data?.ID);
  const [billtoname, setBillToName] = useState(data?.BillToName);
  const [clientname, setClientName] = useState(data?.ClientName);
  const [offc, setOffc] = useState(data?.OFFC);
  const [matterNo, setMatterNo] = useState(data?.MatterNo);

  useEffect(() => {
    setId(data?.ID);
    setBillToName(data?.BillToName);
    setOffc(data?.OFFC);
    setClientName(data?.ClientName);
    setMatterNo(data?.MatterNo);
  }, [data]); // <-- data is external dependency, not row

  ...
```

When using React hooks it is strongly recommended to add the [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) plugin to your eslint configuration so missing and/or incorrect hook dependencies can be easily identified to you via your IDE.

Comment: I would also recommend using ESLint and the [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks), which would show an error about `data` missing from the dependency array.

Comment: @RossAllen Brilliant addition, thanks.

Comment: wow.  i feel like kicking my self.  thanks Drew.  that did the trick

Comment: and thanks for the recommendation !!!!